# problem surrounding my website with a border using div tags

Tags: css, html, css-float

I want a div border to surround my entire website but instead the border is not moving dynamically as i add elements to the page. Instead it just surrounds the first 2 elements, the text and the image but not my tabled menu, but if i delete the div tag surrounding my table then the border will surround the table. I need the div tags to organise my site though so can anyone help me please... The problem seems to come from the float tag in the content_col1 div tag but i need float to place div tags next to each other.

Heres the HTML

```
<div id="content">          
    <div id="content_topTitle">
        Welcome to the greatest local online grocery store the world has ever seen!
    </div>
    <div id="content_images">               
        <img src="image/image1.jpg" />
    </div> 


    <!-- /////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- /////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- /////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- /////////////////////////// -->

    <div id="content_col1">

        <table width = 100% cellpadding = "0" cellspacing = "0">
        <tr>
            <td class = "departments"><a class = "departments" href="">Bakery</a></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td class = "departments"><a class = "departments" href="">Vegetables</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "departments"><a class = "departments" href="">Sweets</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "departments"><a class = "departments" href="">Meats</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "departments"><a class = "departments" href="">Dairy</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "departments"><a class = "departments" href="">Bakery</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "departments"><a class = "departments" href="">Vegetables</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "departments"><a class = "departments" href="">Sweets</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

    </div>  
</div>
```

and here's the CSS

```
#content
{
background: #eee;
border: 5px solid #68accc;
padding: 0px;

}

#content_topTitle
{
text-align: center;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#content_images
{
width:880px;height:200px;
}

#content_col1
{
float: left;
width: 130px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve the problem is to set the overflow on the surrounding element like for example:

```
#content
{
background: #eee;
border: 5px solid #68accc;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

[See an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroen/gY3Ab/1/).

Comment: it didnt help. is using float to place div columns side by side the best solution

Comment: @Kevin Yes it does, take a look at the example I added.

Answer (score 0):

Some fixes are: Clear the float after the div that contains the table. See js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qfPPt/)

Or apply a clear fix class on the wrapper div which takes care of the float and makes the content work. Js fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/qfPPt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need a clearfix on the #content div.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/